# __malloc_hook weird behavior

Tags: c, linux, malloc

i was try to understand `__malloc_hook` by experimenting in actual code
i have tried a lot and still didn't get it right.
so let's start by the first one

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

    void *my_hook(size_t size, const void *caller){
        puts("myHook i called ");
        fflush(stdout);
        return NULL;
    }

    int main(){
        printf("hi so\n");
        __malloc_hook= my_hook;
        printf("%700000s\n","asdf");
        return 0;
    }
```

and here i'm trying to force printf to use my `malloc`  definition (`my_hook`)
it's work but when i change `%700000s` to `%s` it doesn't work
and it never call my (`my_hook`)

---

---

another experiment i did to make gcc happy so he stop throwing many warning

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>


void *my_hook(size_t size, const void *caller){
    puts("myHook i called ");
    fflush(stdout);
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    printf("hi so\n");
    void *(*__malloc_hook)(size_t , const void *)= my_hook;
    printf("%700s\n","asdf");
    return 0;
}
```

but the problem is `my_hook` never used by `printf`  that's happen after gcc became happy

i have no clue what's happen here so if anyone could explain to me

Comment: Don't spam tags.  There is nether any C++ nor assembly language in your question, so those tags are inappropriate.

Comment: this tags help because the solution to my problem might involve debugging the row assembly and also c++ there is similar concept to this concept

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I agree with the asm part, but this is valid C++ code.

Comment: With your second version I get: `prog.c:13:5: error: function ‘__malloc_hook’ is initialized like a variable`. Also, what warnings do you see?

Comment: wait i will edit it

Comment: printf() might call malloc() but it's not sure it will. Take a look at the example code in this man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_hook.3.html

Comment: Yeah start by just calling malloc instead of printf.

Comment: @melpomene if u try it right now no error will show up

Comment: @nora Yes, but now you're creating a local variable in `main` called `__malloc_hook` that doesn't have anything to do with the real `__malloc_hook`. Again, what warnings are you trying to avoid?

Comment: @4386427 in man page  example they restore the old malloc before calling printf

Comment: @melpomene i'm not trying to avoid i'm trying to understand the %700000s vs %s  problem

Comment: Why do you think there is a problem?

Comment: @nora yes, temporarily - to call the real malloc. If your `printf` calls malloc and you return a NULL, printf can't work

Comment: i think is a stack problem or a heap problem

Comment: @4386427 they restore the old malloc because printf use malloc i think if the stack size is big and that the case in my example when i set %70000s the printf can't put it in stack so it use malloc so  it can fit there idk but that what i'm thinking

Comment: @nora they restore and then call `malloc` - i.e. before the printf

Comment: @4386427 ya i know i want to thank u u help me a lot so if u put a answer i will set it as the correct one

Comment: that man page answer my assumption